# Equivalent strings that look exactly the same but arn't equal in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

An public string **ItemSubType** which is assigned a string "primary" by another script is somehow not equal to the string "primary". I've checked for empty characters but there isn't any. I've been absolutly stumped by this but also interested in how this is happening.

```
    Debug.Log("---primary---");
    Debug.Log("---" + ItemSubType + "---");
    if(ItemSubType != "primary")
    {
        Debug.Log("This is ridiculous!");
    }
```

Here is logs:[A picture of the log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jrKOP.png)

Comment: you may use `ItemSubType.equals("primary");` don't know exactly but maybe Unity does a object comparison, and your string object is NOT the temporary "primary" string object

Comment: "*I've checked for empty characters but there isn't any*" -- this would still be my first suspicion. Check again! Or paste it here verbatim

Comment: Check the individual bytes of both strings. Almost certainly there is a hidden character in there somewhere. What is `ItemSubType.Length` for example? Or `ItemSubType[0]`, `ItemSubType[1]`, etc

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for the comments!
After browsing through some other questions, I found **.Trim()**.

Mystically there seems to be an invisible character in the string that isn't a whitespace character, as would be evident by the lack of spaces when adding '---' to either side.

By doing this:

```
ItemSubType = ItemSubType.Trim();
```

It fixed the Issue. To give some context, I pulled the string data from a csv file. I checked the file for any extra spaces but there wasn't any. Not sure if this is related tho.

Comment: You should have let one of the commenters provide the answer really. I suspect your string ended with a CRLF though.

Comment: Yea sorry I'm new to asking questions in stackoverflow. I happed to find the solution and due to the  nature of this  not so straight forward question I thought I might as well  just put it out there while providing some context incase someone finds this issue.

Comment: Sure. I would say that your solution is probably not a good one though. The better options is to fix the reading from the CSV file so it doesn't contain spurious characters.

Comment: Note that there are *loads* of characters which aren't printable -- just adding `---` around a string isn't enough to check whether there are any unprintable characters. You need to look at the actual bytes which form your string

Comment: @DavidG trimming is a valid option to fix this particular case, we can argue on when to do it ;) i'm sure we are both thinking it will be best to do the trim directly after the csv parse

Comment: @TinoZ How can you possibly say it's a good option without knowing the context? I said it's *probably* not a good idea.

Comment: @DavidG i said its a VALID option, if its good, maybe, don't know because of missing context ;) and to blow up the comments, as others already said: you have to take care of ANY unprintable chars `.Trim()` doesn't take care of. When? imho it's best to take care directly at the "root", after parsing the data, wherever it is from and in which format